# jQuery cannot assign to a function result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting the error in the title above in the following code:

```
 $j(".table").delegate('td','click', function(e) {
      //alert($j(this).parent().css('background-color'));
      if ($j(this).parent().css('background-color') == 'transparent') 
        $j(this).parent().css('background-color') = '#eee';
      else {
        $j(this).parent().css('background-color') = 'transparent';
      }
});
```

I don't understand why I'd be getting this error, as I have made sure I am using the assignment operator `==` to compare the strings

Comment: `.css('background-color', '#eee')`

Comment: @abhitalks ahh I knew it was obvious! Submit your answer below as you were first if you'd like me to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Its Ok. You may please accept any answer you deem useful. In fact after seeing some of the answers here (which are more thorough), I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues with your question: first one is already [answered by @Mike Vranckx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23737942/1331430), the correct usage of [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) setter is passing a second argument to set as value.

The other problem is that your condition will never be true, I'll address it in this answer. If you fix it in the way I suggest, you won't be needing `.css()`.

---

[Computed CSS values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value), which are returned from `getComputedStyle`/jQuery's `.css()`, are not exactly what you've authored in your code -- they suffer transformations when parsed into the CSSOM.

For instance, in Chrome:

```
body { background-color: transparent; }
```

```
console.log( $('body').css('background-color') ); //returns "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
```

[See for yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/Grf9J/)

That's why your `$(...).('background-color') == 'transparent'` condition is always false.

---

The most clean and cross-browser solution is to apply styling with classes ([`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)) and do conditional checks with [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

In your case though, `.toggleClass` should suffice. Here's a simple way to write your logic ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBB4s/1/)):

```
$j(".table").on('click', 'td', function() {
    $j(this).parent().toggleClass('bg-gray');
});
```

```
.bg-gray {
    background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: +1 especially for the pre-edit answer regarding the comparison!

Comment: @abhitalks thanks, and yes, though that part was already answered, it is still worth noting nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

To set / change the *background-color* property, you need to pass it as a second argument:

```
$j(this).parent().css('background-color', '#eee');
```

Answer (score 0):

While compare using background color better to use rgba like this

```
$j(this).parent().css('background-color', 'rgb(0,0,0)');
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign value to css, pass the value as a second argument.
 The below line will change to

```
 $j(this).parent().css('background-color') = '#eee';
```

The following Line

```
 $j(this).parent().css('background-color','#eee');
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner, faster, and easier to modify to use a CSS class :

```
.table td { background-color: transparent; }
.foo { background-color: #EEE; }
```

And

```
$j( '.table' ).delegate( 'td', 'click', function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'foo' );
});
```

Also avoid using reserved words like "table" for class names, it's confusing.