# Display "Approved" or "Rejected" on input box with if / else jquery statment

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to display either "Approved" or "Rejected" on input box based on the comparison of two values on other input boxes. I don't know how best to write the if else statement. I've tried to writing the statement below, but it doesn't work.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#txtLon, #txtPro, #txtLim, #txtPer").on("keyup", calc);

  function calc() {
    $("#txtPer").val((Number($("#txtLon").val()) / Number($("#txtPro").val())) * 100);
    if (Number($("#txtPer").val()) <= Number($("#txtLim").val())) {
      $("#txtCom").text() = "Approved";
    } else {
      $("#txtCom").text() = "Rejected";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtLon" required />
<input type="text" id="txtPro" required />
<input type="text" id="txtLim" value="66.67" readonly />

<input type="text" id="txtPer" readonly />
<input type="text" id="txtCom" readonly />
```

Comment: Check your console to see the errors you are getting.

Comment: *but it doesn't work.* is not an error description. Tell us what this means in detail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery cannot assign to a function result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737896/jquery-cannot-assign-to-a-function-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues.

1. Use .val()
2. Use `.text("Approved")` instead of `.text() = "Approved";`
3. Test division by 0
4. Stay DRY (I Use a ternary here)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#txtLon, #txtPro, #txtLim").on("input", calc);

  function calc() {
    var loan = Number($("#txtLon").val());
    var profit = Number($("#txtPro").val());
    var limit = Number($("#txtLim").val());
    var percentage = profit === 0 ? 0 : (loan / profit) * 100; // test division by 0

    $("#txtPer").val(percentage.toFixed(2)); // toFixed(2) for precision

    // Using ternary operator to stay DRY
    $("#txtCom").val(percentage <= limit ? "Approved" : "Rejected");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtLon" required />
<input type="text" id="txtPro" required />
<input type="text" id="txtLim" value="66.67" readonly />

<input type="text" id="txtPer" readonly />
<input type="text" id="txtCom" readonly />
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan, just what I wanted to happen.